# Eslint bug when declaring variables into constructor TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

this is my code in TypeScript :

```
class Snake {
constructor(
    public x: number,       // error 'x' is defined but never used
    public y: number,       // error 'y' is defined but never used
    public size = 10,       // error 'size' is assigned a value but never used
    public color = (() => { 
        const tab = new Array(6).fill(0);
        return `#${tab.map(() => (Math.random() * 0xF << 0).toString(16)).join('')}`;
    })(),                   // error 'color' is assigned a value but never used
) { }

update() {
    const coef = (): number => {
        const nb = Math.round(Math.random());
        return nb === 0 ? -1 : 1;
    };
    this.x += Math.random() * 10 * coef();
    this.y += Math.random() * 10 * coef();
}
...
```

I got eslint installed and it tells me for all the variables :
'is defined but never used' and right under it I use them. I think eslint doesn't understand the declaration inside the constructor parentheses but I'm not sure. I use this method of declaration very often so if I can fix this it I'll be happy

```
{
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
},
"extends": [
    "airbnb-base"
],
"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
},
"plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint"
],
"rules": {
    "no-restricted-globals": "off",
    "consistent-return": "off", 
    "no-return-assign": "off", 
    "prefer-const": "off", 
    "no-param-reassign": "off", 
    "block-scoped-var": "off", 
    "no-use-before-define": "off", 
    "no-undef": "warn", 
    "no-unused-vars": "warn", 
    "no-plusplus": "off", 
    "no-var": "off", 
    "vars-on-top": "off", 
    "indent": [
        "error",
        4
    ], 
    "no-console": "off", 
    "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": "off", 
    "linebreak-style": "off", window
    "class-methods-use-this": "off", 
    "no-empty": "off", 
    "no-constant-condition": "off", 
    "nonblock-statement-body-position": [
        "error",
        "below"
    ], 
    "curly": "off", 
    "no-useless-constructor": "off",
    "no-empty-function": "off",
    "no-bitwise": "off"
}
```

Here is my .eslint.json, the error come from 'no-unused-vars'

Comment: Can you show your eslint config, please? What is the rule that is causing this warning?

Comment: I added it in a comment

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include it, answer posts are reserved for solutions

Comment: Looks like you will need to use `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` instead of `no-unused-vars`. Only the former handles TypeScript properly.

Comment: Thank you it works !! I edit my post as you recommended. I'm new to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

The below line has error:

```
"linebreak-style": "off", window
```

The `window` word is extra.

It should be

```
"linebreak-style": "off",
```

If not, eslint config is shown as invalid, as of today.